# Ant copy with different basedir

Tags: ant

Given the directory structure:

```
root
    build.xml
    folderA
        file1
        file2
    folderB
        file3
```

I'm trying to copy the files in folderA into folderB, when I try, it ends up putting folderA in folderB so I end up with:

```
folderB
    folderA
        file1
        file2
    file3
```

I just want the files copied across with the same structure so I end up with:

```
folderB
    file1
    file2
    file3
```

My Ant task looks like this:

```
<copy todir="folderB">
    <fileset dir="folderA">
        <include name="file*" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Any hints?

**edit:** I can't use flatten as there is a directory structure beneath folderA that needs to be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

```
<copy todir="folderB">
    <fileset dir="folderA/">
        <include name="file*" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

This works.  Note the trailing slash in *dir="folderA/"*.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually really close just need to create the directory first if you want to maintain the folder structure after copy.

```
<target name="copy">
    <mkdir dir="folderB/folderA"/>
    <copy todir="folderB/folderA">
        <fileset dir="folderA"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Comment: This shouldn't matter.  Copy will create any directories that are needed.